# Mark activate -> delete text. Can't store region to Registers

Tags: registers

Linux Mint 20
Emacs 27.2.

I want to store text to the Emacs Registers.

So here steps:

1. Some text to mark.
2. Mark activate by C-SPC
   [image]
3. Fn-> arrow right to  select whole line
   [image]
4. Now I want to save region to Register. I try this
   C-x r
5. But the whole line **is gone**.
   As result nothing to store in the Register

Comment: Your recipe is incomplete, so the question is unclear. `C-x r` is normally a prefix key. Did you hit another key after that? Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Maybe you meant that you use `C-x r s` (command `copy-to-register`)? If so, it should just work. See previous comment for how to find the culprit.

Comment: You can either delete your question, if you think it and the answer won't help anyone, or clarify your question a bit and post your answer. You can accept your own answer. Please consider doing one of those. Comments can be deleted at any time - Q&A need to stand on their own (only they are searchable).

Comment: IOW, what makes the text disappear is just `C-x`, since in `cua-mode` it does a "cut" on the *active* region. The doc string of `cua-mode` says "The C-x and C-c keys only do cut and copy when the
region is active, so in most cases, they do not conflict with the
normal function of these prefix keys" so you might keep `cua-mode`, but make sure that the region is *NOT* active before you use a keybinding with such a prefix, e.g. by pressing `C-g`: the highlight will disappear but the region is still defined (do `C-x C-x` which switches `point` and `mark` to verify), so doing `C-x r s` works.

Comment: @NickD Thanks. I didn't know that region is still defined when press C-g.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I use: (cua-mode t). After disable "cua mode" the problem is gone. And now "C-x r s" success work